# Variable named 'id' does not work in Angular interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I'm learning Angular, running CLI version 8.3.8

So I've just spent several hours trying to figure out why does naming such as below not work:

user.ts

```
export class User {
    id: number
...
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'details/:id', component: UserDetailComponent }
...
```

user-list.component.html

```
<a *ngFor="let user of users" routerLink="/details/{{ user.id }}">
    <span>{{user.id}}</span>
...
```

Every other file has every parameter corresponding to the user.id named just 'id'.

When I click on the link from *user-list.component.html* I get the following error:

```
core.js:6014
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'detail'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'detail'
...
```

and also the `user.id` in the `<span>` is not displayed.

After messing around with routerLinks and paths I started randomly changing 'id' to 'userId' and when *user-list.component.html* looks like this:

```
<a *ngFor="let user of users" routerLink="/detail/{{ user.userId }}">
```

it works without making any other changes to other files.
Same goes for the `<span>` element.

I also encountered opposite situation where another property - `user.name` will be displayed well with `{{ user.name }}`, but changing the name of the attribute to `user.userName` and replacing it everywhere, like `{{ user.userName }}` does not work and the name is not displayed.

The user data is retrieved from a simple server setup where property names of `User` java bean are `userId` and `name`, so I reckon it has to do something with that, but why is the component template the only place where I need  the property names in the server and client to match? (and why is *user.service.ts* not affected by this at all with all its http requests?)

Comment: If the attribute on the object you're dealing with is actually named `usedId`, why *would* that work?

Comment: @jonsharpe I thought that `{{ user.id }}` is a reference of the User object created in the component of class specified in the user.ts file and not the one that I get from the server

Comment: But are you actually using an object you built to that definition, or just whatever you got from the server? Maybe your object definition should match what you're actually going to get?

Comment: Swap to this syntax and see if that fixes your issue: `[routerLink]="['/detail', user.userId]"`

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok I think it might have to do with the fact that the `users: Users[]` in the user-list.component has its value set with `getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
  }` so it overwrites property names too

Comment: @Zze why would changing the syntax change the *value*?

Comment: What do you mean *"overwrites property names"*? They were never actually `User`s, they never had an `id` property; they had a `userId` property. The problem is most likely that you've lied to the HttpClient about the shape of the server's response - see https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok I think that I misunderstood the purpose of class in the client. I was thinking of it like the view used the instances of User defined in user.ts that only had property values provided by the server.